# How long can a delayed packet persist?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, delay

I read a little about PAWS (Protection Against Wrapping Sequence). It's very interesting. I didn't know such complicated things are implemented to guarantee the reliability of TCP. Without PAWS, in the case of high data rate, a delayed old packet can be received and regarded as the new packet by mistake.

I didn't think much about this before. But now I started to wonder how long a packet can stay in network (Especially UDP packet if the type of packet matters). A packet can be delayed, temporarily stay in the network before it's delivered. But it can only stay for a short period of time, right?

In other words, how much time does it take to wait for a (UDP) packet before concluding that it won't come?

If there is an answer, then how is it determined? How to estimate it? (for writing programs related to timeout of packet.)

---

A simplified example: A server received 2 UDP packets. Each contains an integer to indicate the order. It got No.1 and No.3. It knows No.2 is either delayed or lost. After a period of time, No.2 still doesn't come then it concludes the packet is lost. The packet doesn't exist anymore. (So it won't cause any trouble for new packets in the future, similar to the problem PAWS aims to solve.) But how long should the the server wait before concluding No.2 doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: Based on your edit, that is up to the application using UDP. UDP itself is not looking for any particular packet in any particular order. The question doesn't make any sense from a network protocol perspective; this is an application question. Some applications care, and they have implemented their own reliability procedures, or they use TCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [RFC 791 #3.2](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt):

> Time to Live
>
> The time to live is set by the sender to the maximum time the
>       datagram is allowed to be in the internet system.  If the datagram
>       is in the internet system longer than the time to live, then the
>       datagram must be destroyed.
>
> This field must be decreased at each point that the internet header
>       is processed to reflect the time spent processing the datagram.
>       Even if no local information is available on the time actually
>       spent, the field must be decremented by 1.  The time is measured in
>       units of seconds (i.e. the value 1 means one second).  Thus, the
>       maximum time to live is 255 seconds or 4.25 minutes.  Since every
>       module that processes a datagram must decrease the TTL by at least
>       one even if it process the datagram in less than a second, the TTL
>       must be thought of only as an upper bound on the time a datagram may
>       exist.  The intention is to cause undeliverable datagrams to be
>       discarded, and to bound the maximum datagram lifetime.

Comment: That is for IP itself, and it places an upper bound on how long an IP packet can live on the network before being discarded. It doesn't address how long an application will wait for a UDP segment before believing it won't arrive, and, possibly, re-requesting the sender to send another. UDP is not waiting on a particular packet to arrive, so it can't be concerned whether or not it is lost. If an application has mitigations for UDP's lack of guarantees, it is application dependent, and it will vary from application to application. Most use UDP because they don't care.

Comment: @RonMaupin It is for IP itself, and, as a UDP datagram cannot outlive the IP packet it is encapsulated in, it therefore doesn't make sense for an application to wait any longer than the IP TTL before concluding that a UDP datagram is lost. I haven't stated anywhere that UDP is 'concerned whether or not it is lost'. The IP TTL provides an upper bound for what an application should do.

Comment: My point to the OP is that, if an application cares about receiving UDP segments in a certain time frame (most applications that do care will wait much less time than the IP timeout), it is dependent on the application to determine that time period, not UDP since UDP itself doesn't care. UDP is not expecting the next packet so it doesn't know whether or not it is missing, late, or out of order.

Comment: @RonMaupin You don't need to teach me about UDP. If you're addressing yourself to the OP you should clearly so mark your comments, or comment under his question. But you seem to be barking up the wrong tree. The OP's 'simplified example' is clearly about the applicaton waiting, not UDP.

Answer (score 2):

UDP is a fire-and-forget, best-effort protocol. There is no expectation by the receiving host that the UDP packet is coming. Upper layers can use their own guarantees or expectations, but UDP has none.

UDP doesn't wait on packets the way TCP does.

Comment: I mean a UDP packet spends some time traveling. A packet can even reach destination earlier than its previous packet. So how long can the travel takes at most?

Comment: You don't understand that UDP doesn't care about that. It is important to TCP, but a UDP packet gets there when it gets there, or it doesn't, and UDP doesn't care. An application using UDP may care, but that is application dependent, and UDP doesn't care.